# Google Bigquery Storage Write API apache beam triggering frequency

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam

I am trying to use the new Google BigQuery Storage Write API in a Dataflow job using Beam.
I am using

```
BigQueryIO<Pair<String,String>>write().withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STORAGE_WRITE_API)
```

however when I run it I get an error saying

```
When writing an unbounded PCollection via FILE_LOADS or STORAGE_API_WRITES, triggering frequency must be specified
```

however the beam docs (https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.7.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.html#withTriggeringFrequency-org.joda.time.Duration) for `triggeringFrequency` say

```
This is only applicable when the write method is set to BigQueryIO.Write.Method.FILE_LOADS, and only when writing an unbounded PCollection.
```

To be clear, I am using the `STORAGE_WRITE_API` method, not `FILE_LOADS`

I am confused as to why it is asking me to include the `triggeringFrequency` field?

**edit**: Documentation on this new storage write API is poor but I am thinking that it, under the hood, is doing a form of batching so, like the `FILE` method, it needs some frequency to determine the rate of batching

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java#L2622) where triggering frequency is fetched, the storage api triggering frequency is from the BigQueryOptions iff the triggeringFrequency of the IO is not set, see [getStorageApiTriggeringFrequency(BigQueryOptions options)](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/69a8567efd6b1f6eb3514403f7d580d0626d2e4a/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java#L2571).

So

> When writing an unbounded PCollection via FILE_LOADS or STORAGE_API_WRITES, triggering frequency must be specified

is correct.

But

> This is only applicable when the write method is set to BigQueryIO.Write.Method.FILE_LOADS, and only when writing an unbounded PCollection.

is wrong.

Should be

This is only applicable when the write method is set to BigQueryIO.Write.Method.FILE_LOADS or BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STORAGE_WRITE_API, and only when writing an unbounded PCollection.

Ideally, you probably should set it through the BigQueryOptions.setStorageWriteApiTriggeringFrequencySec().

I think the documentation is intentionally hiding the implementation details of overriding the options through the I/O class builder itself.